# Why does an error is popping up while executing Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()

Tags: r

I am setting up a code and I am trying to execute a code (taken from You Tube on NLP). I am getting error in the function Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()

```
install.packages("rJava")
install.packages("NLP")
install.packages('openNLP')
require(NLP)
require(rJava)
require(openNLP)
s <- paste(c("Pierre VInken, 61 years old, will join the board as a 
","nonexecutive director Nov. 29. \n","Mr. Vinken  is chairman of Elsevier 
N.V.,","the dutch publishing group."),collapse = "")
s <- as.String(s)
sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
```

But I am getting the below error

```
Error in Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator() : 
could not find function "Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator"
```

May I Know how to rectify this?

Comment: sometimes, if you've had your R session open for a long time, it starts to act a little buggy. Can you restart R and see if the error arises again? If it does, can you add `sessionInfo()` to your question?

Comment: Nope. Still the same. What does sessionInfo() do here

Comment: ['sessionInfo()'](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/sessionInfo.html) When the error seems to make no sense, as the one you’re getting seems to, sometimes it’s your settings.

Comment: Still getting the same error.